# Is there something similar to ruby send method in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

So I wonder if I can do something similar to this in Elixir?

```
def some_method(some_param) # a symbol for example
  send(some_param)
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Kernel.apply/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3).

```
apply(Enum, :reverse, [[1, 2, 3]])
```

## An example:

With a module like this:

```
defmodule Apply do
  def dynamic(method_name, params) do
    apply(Apply, method_name, params)
  end

  def method1(params) do
    IO.puts "Method 1, called by " <> params
  end

  def method2(params) do
    IO.puts "Method 2, called by " <> params
  end
end
```

I can invoke a specific function using it's name:

```
iex(1)> c("apply.ex")
[Apply]

iex(2)> Apply.dynamic(:method1, ["Hey"])
Method 1, called by Hey
:ok

iex(3)> Apply.dynamic(:method2, ["Hey"])
Method 2, called by Hey
:ok
```

Comment: `apply` is similar to `public_send`. It would be similar to send if a private function could be called from anywhere, right?